# Last Inserted Prefixed ID

Tags: mysql

We have a table with a column containing prefixed auto-generated ID. (i.e. `ABC-000001`, `ABC-000002`, etc). How do we get the last inserted ID here?

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` doesn't help here. Thanks.

NOT for PHP.

Comment: you can't, not without writing your own id generator. mysql auto_increments only work for ints, and doesn't do prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done; not in the general case, if we take "last inserted ID" to mean the value of the ID column from the row that was most recently inserted into a table.

To get that, you'd need need some way to determine which row was the "most recently inserted" row. For example, storing a datetime or timestamp column that records the time when the row is inserted. (Delving into how you would go about doing that, that goes beyond the question you asked.)

As another alternative, the generator of the "prefixed auto-generated ID" could keep a record of the last ID value that was generated. But there's no guarantee that the value that it auto-generated was actually stored as the ID value in a row in the table.

---

It would be possible to write an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. That trigger could record the value of the ID column in a separate table. And you could retrieve the value from that second table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_ai 
AFTER INSERT ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  -- a reference `new`.`ID` gets the ID column from the row just inserted
  -- store this in a second table

END;
```

You'd want to have only one row in that second table, and you'd want the trigger to update that row. You could use a dummy primary key, and use a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`, or if you assume that a row is there, you could just perform the UPDATE. (I'm just saying this might be a possible approach, but the implementation seems fragile to me.)

---

What I'm wondering, of course, is what problem is being solved by the requirement to get the "last inserted" "prefixed auto-generated ID".

Comment: Thank you so much [spencer7593](http://stackoverflow.com/users/107744/spencer7593)! This is such a valuable input. We are inserting rows to table from Java app via SP call. Auto ID will be generated once other columns are populated. We will then return this ID to the UI.

Comment: Having the process that performs the insert return the `ID` value of a row it inserts to the table is a much different specification than the more general "get the last inserted ID".  An AFTER INSERT trigger can store the `ID` value of the column in a user variable, and the same database session that performs the insert can run a query to retrieve the value of the user variable. And you likely would want a corresponding BEFORE INSERT trigger to clear out that user variable.